# $.ajax “Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation”

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For some reason it's coming up with “Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation” error and I can't figure it out why, any ideas?

```
AutomatedEmailSend: function(ele) {
        var $ele = $(ele);

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("ShopId", $ele.data("shopid"));
        formData.append("AutomatedEmailAddress", $("#AutomatedEmailAddress").val());
        formData.append("AutomatedEmailEnabled", $("#AutomatedEmailEnabled")[0].checked);
        formData.append("AutomatedEmailTime", $("#AutomatedEmailTime").val());

        $.ajax({
            url: $ele.data("url"),
            data: formData,
            method:"POST"
        }).done(function(response) {
            trrNoty("Email sent!");
        }).fail(function(error) {
            trrNoty(error.statusText,"error");
        });
    },
```

Comment: Where does this error is thrown?

Comment: @Justinas just when it hits the $.ajax({ line

Comment: if it is possible then make a js fiddle

Comment: what it returns `$ele.data("url")`  ?

Comment: check your parameters ((formData)) are passing correctly, which means correct value format , will you share sample parameter (formData)values if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using

```
 processData: false
```

Comment: That fixed the problem, could you explain why please?

Comment: By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false. – BOTJr